# Convert Javascript Variable to Coldfusion variable

Tags: javascript, xml, coldfusion

Hi I have the following code.  I am trying to figure out how to get test_xml= xmlEditor.getXmlAsString(); line into a coldfusion variable from this script.

I have tried.

```
 <cfset myXML = qQuery[test_xml]>
```

This returns nothing.  Here is the raw script below.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

```
 //get output xml from edited
$('#xml_output').click(function() {

        try {
            test_xml= xmlEditor.getXmlAsString();
            //file_xml= xmlEditor.W
            //test_xml1= encodeURI(test_xml).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');

            //GLR.messenger.show({msg:"Generating file...", mode:"loading"});
            //GLR.messenger.inform({msg:"File saved Successfully.", mode:"success"});
            $('.final_area').val(test_xml);
            $('.final_xml').css('display','block');

        } catch(e) {
            GLR.messenger.show({msg:"Something went wrong, Please try again later....",mode:"error"});
        }
});
```

Comment: CF and JS are in two different places. Read this: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Comment: I am pulling the JS into a TextArea will the following work
    <cfset testxml = "form.finalxml">

Comment: No, because `"form.finalxml"` is a string. Remove the quotes and (if you have submitted a form containing `<textarea name="finalxml">...</textarea>`) you'll get the contents of the variable instead.

Comment: If you pull the js into a form field, and I suggest hidden rather than textarea, it will become a ColdFusion variable when you submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get a variable back to coldfusion from javascript, you are going to need to look into something like AJAX.

You could use something like this to send the variable to a cfm page:

```
$.post("variable.cfm" + jsvariable,function(data,status){
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

This would sent the `jsvariable` variable back to the coldfusion page, where you could return what you wanted to, what is returned would be in the `data` variable.

Comment: I would point out that this is in some ways the same as doing a form submission; obvious difference/benefit is that it doesn't reload the whole page, but it's important to understand how jQuery's [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method works and to be aware that it's not magic (i.e. it's still doing a HTTP request).